# JSF Hide Negative Mark when using f:convertNumber

Tags: jsf

I want to hide the minus value from the print during formatting in JSF. How can I achieve that.

For Example,

The Value : -340
Need to Display as : 340.00
Not like -340.00 or (340.00)

Is that possible? The current code is like that, but can not hide minus value.

```
<h:outputText value="#{paymentBill.amount}" >
    <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: What about displaying the Absolute of the value?

Comment: Why? What if you owe them money? You're obliged to tell them that, and not mislead them into paying it to you instead of you paying it to them, or crediting them.

Comment: The real situation is like this. Patients are billed. Certain amount of money is paid to the relevant doctor in payment bills. It is a minus amount for the hospital, so in payment slip it goes as minus.

Comment: So why do you want to suppress that fact?

Comment: Patients pay hospital. It is an income for the hospital. So they are recorded as plus. Hospital pay doctors. It is an expense for the hospital. So they are marked as minus within the system. So the collection of BilledBills and PaymentBills, which are both inherited from the Bill Entity will give the exact income. But when minus is marked in the payment slip of the doctors, they require whether some money has been deducted by the hospital. It is a customer requirement. So I have to cater to that requirement. Hope you get my point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's `<h:outputText>` then you can use arbitrary EL expression as its `value`, if you're so dissatisfied with getting absolute value while preparing data in your managed bean, as it's rightly proposed by perissf and fareed, like:

```
value="#{(paymentBill.amount lt 0) ? -paymentBill.amount : paymentBill.amount}"
```

Comment: Thank you. It completely solved my issue easily and logically.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the absolute value of the amount In the backing bean.

Return `Math.abs(amount)` instead of amount.

Comment: This logic belongs to the view, to it would be better applying a function or a logic on view only, not from controller.